# How do you execute or run a python program in your desktop?

Tags: python, execution

I am new into learning python and I was having a hard time running a program (my code) the cmd recognizes that I have a 3.12 Python version but when I run my code which I made using VS StudioCode the file doesn't do anything. I have fixed the directory but it still remain as it is (not recognizing the python file).
To be able to run my code as intended here is the code I did:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def read_task(file1):
    tasks = {}
    if os.path.exists(file1):
        with open(file, 'r')as file:
            for line in file:
                task, completed, creation_date = line.strip().split(',')
                tasks[task] = {'completed': bool(int(completed)), 'creation_date': datetime.strptime(creation_date, '%Y-%m-%d')}
    return task

def write_tasks(file1, tasks):
    with open(file1, 'w') as file:
        for task, details in task.items():
            completed = details['completed']
            creation_date = details[creation_date].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            file.write (f'{task},{int(completed)},{creation_date}\n')

def main():
    file1 = 'task.txt'
    tasks = read_task(file1)

    current_date = datetime.now()
    for task, details in tasks.items():
        completed = details['completed']
        creation_date = details['creation_date']

        if completed and (current_date - creation_date).days >= 7:
            tasks[task][completed]= False

            print ("Current tasks:")

            completed = details['completed']
            print (f'{task}: {"Done" if completed else "To do"}')

            completed_task = input("Enter a completed task: ")
            tasks[completed_task]['completed'] = True

            write_tasks(file1, tasks)

            if __name__ == "__main__":
                main()
```

Comment: The part `if __name__ == '__main__':` should not be included in the main function, but it should be at zero indentation at the end of your file. Does it work if you use `cmd` in you folder and run `python your_script.py`?

Comment: Thank you so much for the syntax correction, yes the cmd can now recognize my file.

Comment: I would really suggest you to check for 'dunder variables in python', they are also called special attributes, could really help understand what & how they work

Answer (score 1):

Wrong indentation for the:

if **name** == "**main**":
main()

it shouldn't be under main function

Comment: ok, but you are not answering the question... _How do you execute or run a python program in your desktop?_

Comment: In the terminal/command line:

ensure you're in the same directory/folder as the file you are writing the code: then type; python name_of_the_file_you_want_to_run.py

ensure you are in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in your code that need to be addressed:

1. In the read_task function, you're returning task instead of tasks.
2. In the write_tasks function, task should be tasks.

Make sure to indent the code correctly and adjust the issues mentioned above. Also, ensure that your task.txt file exists in the same directory as your Python script.

Comment: ok, but you are not answering the question... _How do you execute or run a python program in your desktop?_